# For Ring of Quaternions, does $a + bi +cj + dk = 0$ imply $a,b,c,d = 0$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

Of course, if $a,b,c,d = 0$, then $a + bi +cj + dk = 0$. But having trouble with other direction.

Comment: This is the statement that $1,i,j,k$ are linearly independent, which is true by definition.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley I'm confused. How are you interpreting $i,j,k$ as vectors when $i$ is defined as $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: @beginner $i,j,k$ are "vectors" in the sense that you can multiply them by a real number and add them to other vectors (with a multiplication and addition that "make sense"); that's the only requirement for something to be a "vector" by the mathematical definition.

Comment: @beginner As another example, matrices are not "vectors" in the sense of being a one-dimensional list of numbers, but they can be called "vectors" (i.e. the set of matrices forms a "vector space"). The same can be said about functions, which can similarly be multiplied by real numbers and added to each other.

Comment: @BenGrossmann How do we know $1, i, j,k$ are linearly independent then? How does it hold "by definition"?

Comment: @beginner Well, that will depend on the specific definition that you're working with

Comment: @BenGrossmann $\{a + bi + cj + dk: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: How do we know we cannot build a vector $v$ by combining other vectors through some kind of cancellation or something? Should I interpret this like the way one interprets polynomials? e.g. if $f,g$ are polynomials, even though $f(c) = g(c)$ for all $c$, if they don't share the same coefficients, $f \neq g$?

Comment: @beginner Unfortunately, most definitions appeal to the notion of "formal operations on symbols", and I'm having a hard time finding an authoritative source that explains this idea well. In a nutshell, it comes down to the fact that the relations governing quaternions (e.g. $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1$) are such that every sum/product can be reduced to something of the form $a + bi + cj + dk$. "By definition", any two such expressions are distinct quaternions if (and only if) the coefficients $a,b,c,d$ are not all the same.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah exactly, so it's like the polynomial example I gave?

Comment: @beginner That's exactly right. In some contexts, polynomials that are considered in this fashion are referred to as "formal polynomials" (in the sense that they are polynomials "in form" but not "in function") for this reason.

Comment: @beginner One (in my opinion, inelegant) way to avoid this kind of definition is to define quaternions via a [matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations).

Comment: @BenGrossmann An easier way IMO is just not to talk about formal symbols, but just define $Q$ as the vector space $\mathbb{R^4}$, and define a multiplication operation on it. The elements $1,i,j,k$ are defined to be the standard basis vectors. (and so it is obvious that they are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true but I don't agree with the comments that it's true "by definition"; it depends on how you define the quaternions. Here are $4$ different definitions:

1. The set of formal $\mathbb{R}$-linear combinations $a + bi + cj + dk$, with multiplication determined by $ij = k, jk = i, ki = j, i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$, and the condition that $i, j, k$ anticommute with each other. With this approach $1, i, j, k$ are linearly independent by definition, but you need to prove separately that multiplication is associative.
2. The $\mathbb{R}$-algebra generated by three generators $i, j, k$ subject to the relations $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1$ (you can also remove $k$ and use two generators). With this approach the quaternions are associative by definition but you need to prove that $1, i, j, k$ are linearly independent. You can do this by embedding the quaternions into a matrix algebra, which can also be used as a definition:
3. (and 4) As either a specific set of $2 \times 2$ complex matrices or a specific set of $4 \times 4$ real matrices; you can consult [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations) for details. With this approach the quaternions are associative by definition but you still need to prove that $1, i, j, k$ are linearly independent although it's a lot easier to check this with matrices.